# Ĉu oni uzu "knufli"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mankas al mi verbo en Esperanto. Iu proponis *brakumadi* sed ĝi ne sufiĉe kontentigas min. Temas pri intima ago. Oni sidas aŭ kuŝas apude, eble metas la brakojn ĉirkaŭ unu la alian aŭ karesas unu la alian. Ne nur estas paroj kiuj faras tion, sed ankaŭ familianoj aŭ bestoj. En la angla ekzistas "cuddle" kaj en la sveda "gosa".

Kelkaj homoj uzas *knufli*. Ĝi ne troviĝas en PIV. Ĉu *knufli* estas la plej bona alternativo? Eble estas alia kunmetaĵo, aŭ kombino de vortoj kiu pli bonas.

Answer (score 5):

„knufli” estas uzata en pluraj Esperanto-renkontiĝoj. Ĉu ĝi iam aperos en vortaro, verŝajne dependas de la fakto, ĉu iuj aŭtoroj uzos ĝin ankaŭ skribe.

Answer (score 1):

Persone, mi mem ne konas la vorton "knufli" kaj mi ne sukcesis trovi ĝin en vortaro. Atentu ke *cuddle* havas malsaman signifon en diversaj partoj de la angleparolanta mondo, kaj oni devas scii kiun version de la angla oni tradukas en du-lingva vortaro. Por la usona signifo, Benson proponas "premkaresi" kaj "komfortiĝi kun." Mi scivolas kial oni ne povas simple diri "kuŝi."

Answer (score 0):

La vorto **knufli** nek ekzistas en la tekstaro nek en la ReVo nek en Google Translate. Ĝi ne estas vorto en Esperanto.

> **Karesi** - Delikate kaj ame tuŝeti
>   - http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kares.html#kares.0i

- Mi karesas mian hundon.
- Ni karesas la alian.
- Ŝi karesas min.

Comment: „karesi” estas io alia. Oni kutime karesas per unu mano. Oni knuflas per la tuta korpo. Se vi ne ŝatas la novismon „knufli”, tiam plej proksimas „ĉirkaŭbraki” laŭ mi.

Comment: Guglu je ”knufloj”! Ŝajne iu kreis t-ĉemizon kun la vortoj ”senpagaj knufloj”, do en iuj esperantujoj la vorto certe ekzistas… Interese. Eble ĝi disvastiĝos simile al ”mojosa”?